# Cannot deploy project in MyEclipse for Spring 10

Tags: tomcat, deployment, myeclipse

I have MyEclipse for Spring 10 on Mac OS X 10.7.3. I use Tomcat 6.0.32 installed via Macports 2.0.4, instead of MyEclipse integrated sandbox.

When I tried to deploy my project, it kept giving me

```
SenCal could not be redeployed because it could not be completely removed in the undeployment phase...........
```

I tried stop tomcat then deploy. I tried remove libraries from build path then add them back again, as most people suggested. I even tried reinstall tomcat6. None of these solved my problem.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks,

Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake. The permission on Webapps folder was wrong. Problem solved.